# How works the "eject usb driver" from Gnome?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, unmounting

I have a question for some time in my head:

I have an external hard drive, when I want to dismount it I simply give in the icon that says: "Remove unit safely" in the Nautilus (use **Nautilus** from **Gnome 3.14** in **Debian 8**), but in reality what is the process behind? It's a way to see what really happens? Some kind of logs?

I imagine that the first process is `umount /wherever/its/mount`, but I noticed that when I unmount it using `umount` the led of the external hard drive stays **on** (when Windows OS turn off the led), so: the `umount` command should *also* cuts off the power of the USB port where the hard drive is connected? Or is another command doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`umount` command itself doesn't cut off power to the drive, mounting really means linking a filesystem on drive with a directory, so unmounting just does that - unlinks a mount from particular directory; and as far as Nautilus file manager goes that's not what it uses under the hood, in fact it uses [GMount](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMount.html) objects from the standard Gio API for all GNOME-related type of development.

Without confusing you too much, let me explain it in terms of source code and documentation. Brief search through source code reveals that in [nautilus-file-operations.c](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus/blob/31271dc377475c223d38755a027205545bf6af74/src/nautilus-file-operations.c) file, the `nautilus_file_operations_unmount_mount_full` function calls `do_unmount`, which calls `g_mount_eject_with_operation` function. That last one belongs to [GMount portion of API](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMount.html#g-mount-eject-with-operation).  Ejecting would involve  sync-ing remaining data that needs to be written to the mount, `unmounting` a volume or drive, and then powering it off in case of USB drive or optical disk.

If you're expecting a [shell command that can  power off a drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/532586/295286) just like in Nautilus, there is one via `udisks` or `udisksctl`, and if I'm not mistaken `udisksctl` comes with OSes that use `systemd` (but don't quote me on this last statement, that's an opinion only). That makes use of [UDisks2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks), which is actually another API for handling drives and volumes via [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) interface; it is actually quite nice and I've used for developing [my own indicator on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/830558/295286).

So **TL;DR**:

- Nautilus uses Gio API to handle mounts, but doesn't call any external or standalone command-line utility
- There is command-line equivalent that performs similar operations as Nautilus
- You can always write your own using Gio API, UDisks API, or call external `udisks` or `udisksctl` command.

See also:

- https://askubuntu.com/q/5845/295286

Comment: While I finished to write this question I keep searching for info and I see the link you left me at the end, and that answer me some doubts but your answer complete the "question I had in mind"...very useful information! THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In gnome, the best way to mimic eject of a MYUSB drive within nautilus is

```
$ gio mount -e /media/dzmanto/MYUSB
```

It does not require root privileges.